# Is there a way to only update a single property value with Google Cloud Datastore?

Tags: nosql, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, document-database

My project has an `Article` kind. Then, there is a `Block` kind. Each `Block` has an article as parent entity; therefore, each article is made up of several `Block` entities. Each `Block` has an order **property** so the end-user can order them.

On the frontend, users can add a new `Block` or update an existing one. Obviously, by moving a `Block` up, it changes its own order but fatally, it also changes (+1) each of the subsequent `Block` entities.

So far, for every update the user saves, I retrieve all `Block` entities with an order equal or greater than the newly saved one, and update each of them.

**Is there are way to simply update one property (`order`) using the PHP library?**

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot update just a property of an entity, you have to update the entire entity. From [Updating an entity](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#updating_an_entity):

> To update an existing entity, modify the properties of the entity
>   previously retrieved and store it using the key:
>
> ```
> $transaction = $datastore->transaction();
> $key = $datastore->key('Task', 'sampleTask');
> $task = $transaction->lookup($key);
> $task['priority'] = 5;
> $transaction->upsert($task);
> $transaction->commit();
> ```
>
> The provided data overwrites the existing entity. The entire object
>   must be sent to Cloud Datastore. [...]
>
> ```
> **Note:** To delete a property, remove the property from the entity, then save the entity.
> ```